# T-SQL inner query like join based off IN results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that has a subquery listing 2 names:

- Coop
- Bro

Code:

```
Select LastName 
From Managers 
Where Type = prefix;
```

I need to have the outer query use this above sub-query in something like an 'IN' statement, but it's not an exact match, but rather a BEGINS WITH.  Something like the following with + '%':

```
Select *
From Employees
Where LastName In (Select LastName + '%'
                   From Managers
                   Where Type = prefix)
```

Desired query would return back outer query results such as:

- Cooper
- Coopersmith
- Coopmoth
- Brown
- Brownly
- Bronnan

...but, this is not working.  I get 0 results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`.  Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
Select e.*
from Employees e
where exists (select 1
              from managers m
              where type = prefix and
                    e.LastName like m.LastName + '%'
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it with similar to:

```
select * from employees e
   inner join Managers m on e.lastname like m.lastname + '%' and m.type = prefix
```